# How to check whether DNS record for domain exist in WHOIS database on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

CASE 1: if "facebook.com" exist in WHOIS database (already registered) then Matlab will return 0
[image]

CASE 2: if "fghasd.com" do not exist in WHOIS database (not yet registered) then Matlab will return 1
[image]

I have checked through Matlab, there have no function for this situation.
Is there any method to solve?

Comment: How would you do it *outside* of MATLAB, from some kind of command line or shell script (instead of looking at at web page)?  Then, whatever you're doing from the shell, you can call from within MATLAB via the `system` command (or other mechanisms).

Comment: I am doing at the WHOIS database, check whether the domain name has already exist or not, but I do not have the idea to link with Matlab for generating the results (0 or 1). I can check the domain name at WHOIS, then manually categorize that in Matlab (if exist then I put 0 in Matlab array, else 1), but this seems like make no sense since I can do it manually by putting 0 or 1 for the output. Is there any idea that can link to WHOIS database then I just have to call the function to check the domain name at Matlab instead of checking at WHOIS database website?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the response output for "trigger words" to determine if the result was available, registered or some other status.

However, because there is no standard for the format of a whois response you'll have to figure out what these "triggers" are.  Here are some examples used on the dotology.co.uk site:

```
         "no match",
         "not found",
         "no data found",
         "status:\tavailable",
         "no entries found",
         "unknown domain",
         "no domain records were found to match",
         "status: not registered",
         "is available for registration",
         "domain status: available",
         "no found"
```

and..

```
        "not supported",
        "prohibited string",
        "is not valid!"
```

Comment: I have to subscribe WHOIS database in order to access for the results which can connect to my Matlab is it? and it is not free...
http://www.ipserverone.info/domain-related/how-to-subscribe-whois-privacy-protection-with-ipserverone-customer-portal/
got any other method?